# Stored Procedures and Cursors in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Employee and Department. They look like so:

```
Employee
Name
SSN
DeptID
Salary

Department
DName
DId
Total_Sal
```

Department.total_sal is a sum of all of the employee's salary who belong to that Department. I need a stored procedure that utilizes a cursor to iterate through each employee, and update the corresponding department's salary. I have never worked with Cursors or Stored procedures before and I am a bit confused with how to iterate through one table but update another. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Another quick question, I like to do all of my sql work in SQLFIDDLE, does anyone know if it also supports stored procedures/cursors?

Here is my first attempt, I suppose it would be a good idea to wipe Department.Total_sal at the beginning of this as well?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cur_sal

CREATE PROCEDURE cur_sal
  BEGIN
    DECLARE e_sal, e_dno INT;
    DECLARE d_sal, d_dno INT;
    DECLARE cur_emp CURSOR FOR SELECT salary, DeptId FROM employee;
    DECLARE cur_dep CURSOR FOR SELECT DId, Total_sal FROM department;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur_emp;
    OPEN cur_dep;


    r_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur_emp INTO e_sal, e_dno;
      FETCH cur_dep INTO d_sal, d_dno;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE r_loop;
      END IF;

      IF e_dno = d_dno THEN
        UPDATE department SET total_sal = total_sal + e_sal;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_emp;
    CLOSE cur_dep;
  END //
```

Comment: you need to show what you have tried first

Comment: Why do you want to iterate with a cursor? A single update query with a join can do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

there's no need to use cursors to do this.  There are multiple ways of achieving the same results including joins and sub selects.  In the code below I've used a sub select  (because I have to go back to work and it's quick):

Drop this into the Build Scheme section:

```
-- create the tables
CREATE TABLE Employee 
    (
    Name varchar(50),
    SSN varchar(50),
    DeptID int,
    Salary float
    );

CREATE TABLE Department 
    (
    DName varchar(50),
    DId int,
    Total_Sal float
    );

-- insert default values
insert into Employee (name,ssn,deptid,salary)
values('Mr Test', '12345a', 1,10000);

insert into Employee (name,ssn,deptid,salary)
values('Mr Tester', '12345b', 1,33000);

-- notice the total_sal is 63000
insert into department (DName, DID, total_sal)
values('Test department',1,63000);

-- now we update the total_sal to be the sum of everyone in that department
update Department 
set total_sal = (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM employee where employee.DeptID = Department.DID)
```

In the executable section run this:

```
select * from department
```

and you'll notice that the total_sal is now 43000 rather than the initial 63000 value that was inserted.

The update statement that I used would iterate through each department.

Here is the SQLFiddle: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be26/1)

Of if you insist on using a cursor you could do something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSalaries()
BEGIN

  -- Cursor Example
  declare DeptID INTEGER;
  declare TotalSalary FLOAT;

  declare SalaryCursor Cursor for select DId, 
    (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM employee where employee.DeptID = Department.DID) from department

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    open SalaryCursor
      FETCH SalaryCursor INTO DeptID, TotalSalary;

    get_Salary: LOOP

      update Department 
      set total_sal = TotalSalary
      WHERE DID = DeptID

    END LOOP get_Salary;

  CLOSE SalaryCursor;
END
```

Comment: PaulG, thank you for your advice. I am aware that there are much easier and more efficient ways to achieve the goal here. I however have been tasked to do it specifically with a Stored Procedure/Cursor.

Comment: you can put this in a stored procedure, but you still don't need a cursor lol

Comment: @Hituptony yes I am aware that cursors are rather inefficient, however I do not have a choice in this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cur_sal
  BEGIN
    DECLARE e_sal, e_dno INT;
    DECLARE sum_sal INT
    DECLARE d_sal, d_dno INT;
    DECLARE cur_emp CURSOR FOR SELECT salary, Dno FROM employee;
    DECLARE cur_dep CURSOR FOR SELECT Dno, Total_sal FROM department;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur_emp;
    OPEN cur_dep;


    r_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur_emp INTO e_sal, e_dno;
      FETCH cur_dep INTO d_sal, d_dno;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE r_loop;
      END IF;

      IF e_dno = d_dno THEN
         SET sum_sal = sum_sal + e_sal;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
UPDATE department SET total_sal = sum_sal where DId = Dno;
    CLOSE cur_emp;
    CLOSE cur_dep;
  END //
```

Here you are pretty close I think, you want to use a temp variable to hold the sum of all transactions until you reach the end of the loop. When you get to the end you update the Department Salary with your summed up value. I just used sum_sal.

Update statement needs a where clause, you're basically going to have your cursor full of the values you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use a temporary sum variable, that is a good idea. I have a question about your solution though, how will it deal with different departments?